# Apple Watch eSIM configuration

Tags: apple-watch

When the Apple Watch [eSIM is configured](https://techcrunch.com/2017/09/12/the-cellular-enabled-apple-watch-has-the-sim-built-in/):

- Can the eSIM be reconfigured if I replace the SIM card (same carrier)?
- Is the eSIM **locked** to a carrier?

The cited article is unclear and I hope that someone with experience configuring watches could comment.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the eSIM be reconfigured if I switch carriers?

Yes.

> Is the eSIM locked to a carrier?

No.